# What is the best programmable router?

Tags: programmable

I have a programming background and would like to buy a programmable router (probably python as the language, but I'm open to others ), in order to control my kids internet use. I know there are prebuilt systems out there, but I'd like the increased flexibility , with the ability to create my own scripts.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "programmable"? What do you want the scripts to do? The code for routers is usually compiled and part of the linux kernel or firmware on the router. It would be dangerous and likely cause many compatibility issues to try and replace that code with your own. Some routers support open source firmware like OpenWRT, which you could modify and compile yourself to do whatever you want.

Comment: Hi - Sorry for not explaining myself well. I'm not looking to control things at the packet level, but  I'd like to be able to write scripts to allow certain devices on the network at certain times or control what FQDN are accesssed. as an example I want to allow fortnite for 1 hour a day.

Comment: Ok then that kind of functionality is available quite a few consumer routers in the first place. Have you done much research into what is available? You don't need to write code at all because the admin page on these routers has options to set up schedules and domain blocking. Some of the more expensive routers are just linux comptuers too so you could potentially run some python scripts from cron if you really needed that; Presumably to edit config files to change how the router is configured on a schedule.